# $.get is not a function in window.function definition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $.get is not a function

I would understand if I haven't imported `jquery` before loading this function

```
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        window.loadCurrentLocation = function(){

            $.get("{% url "locations:ajax_get_current_location" %}").done(function (data) {
                    {#                TODO: Osetrit ak neexistuje#}
                    $('#id_my_current_location').text(data.name);
                }
            )
        };

        window.setUserLocation = function(){


            var place_id = $('#id_this_place_id').val();
            var name = $('#id_this_name').val();
            $.get("{% url "locations:ajax_set_current_user_location" %}?place_id=" + place_id + "&name=" + name).done(function (data) {
                loadCurrentLocation();
            })
        }
    </script>
```

Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: Can you debug what $ evaluates at that point? Does every integrity check importing these scripts success?

Comment: In console: >$
<ƒ (a,b){return new r.fn.init(a,b)}

Comment: When are you calling setUserLocation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're loading in the slim version of jQuery instead of the full version. The slim version doesn't have `$.ajax`, `$.get` or `$.post` helpers.

Answer (score 1):

Found this on web

You are using the slim version of jQuery, which doesn't have AJAX(in your case the $.get() function).

Use the complete build, available here http://jquery.com/download/, such as:

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js